# python regex two words

Tags: python, regex

I have tones of string data and want to find all "iphone case" or "iPhone 6 case" or "iphone cases" in the string and delete by using regexp.

```
tweet=re.sub(r'iphone\s[case]+', 'DELETESENTENCE', tweet)
tweet=re.sub(r'[iphone\s]+[0-6]+[\scase]+', 'DELETESENTENCE', tweet)
```

I used to the regexp above and later I kill all the text including `DELETESENTENCE`.

But I just wonder more decent way of clearing text rather than killing individually or replacing the pattern individually

for example I have  `lst=['iPhone case', 'iPhone battery', 'iPhone film']`

and `re(r'lst','DELETESENTENCE','tweet)`  <== obviously this does not work.

Comment: What is your question? Your code works, right? Why do you want to change it? If we can understand your motivation, we can better understand which advice to offer :)

Comment: @MagnusHoff My question is "Is there a way that I can combine those two regexp?" And If I have list of two words as described above, how can I kill them with regexp?

Comment: Ah, thanks. The answers below seem correct. In general you can combine regular expressions with the *or* operator, `|`. For example, if you want to match both `exp 1` and `exp 2`, you can combine them like this: `(exp 1)|(exp 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex can be joined by a "or" condition with the column "|" character.
This should work in your case :

```
tweet=re.sub('|'.join(lst), 'DELETESENTENCE', tweet)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I well understand, but is that does what you want:

```
'iphone(?:\s+[0-6])?\s+cases?'
```

This will match:

```
iphone case
iPhone 6 case
iphone cases
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you have some issues in the regexes. `[case]+` means "any of the "c", "a", "s", "e" characters 1 or more times", I guess it is not what you want.

If you want to just be able to match 2 words "iphone" and "case", you can use:

```
  tweet=re.sub(r'(?i)\b(?:iphone|case)\b', 'DELETESENTENCE', tweet)
```

If you just need to remove the 2 words that are separated with a number, then

```
  tweet=re.sub(r'(?i)\biphone\s+[0-9]+\s+case\b', 'DELETESENTENCE', tweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to match "IPhone", followed by an optional "6", followed by "case" or "cases" (this also matches "iphone 6 case**s**", but I assume you don't mind).

Rather than edit the string and then delete (roundabout!), you could do it like this:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    if re.search(r"iphone\s+(6\s+)?cases?", tweet, re.IGNORECASE):
        <delete or mark message for deletion>
```

Or in one step:

```
filtered_tweets = [ tweet for tweet in tweets if not 
    re.search(r"iphone\s+(6\s+)?cases?", tweet, re.IGNORECASE) ]
```